# how to perform migration for django table created without any app

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django project in which I have not created any app, I directly wrote models for the project in models.py file inside project folder.
But whenever I perform

```
python manage makemigrations
```

it says : No changes detected

so when I perform

```
python manage migrate
```

it says :   No migrations to apply.

So is there any different way to perform migrations if you are directly writing your models without creating any App for django project

Answer (score 0):

You should add your app to django `INSTALLED_APPS` settings, if not, then, you dont have an django app.

Comment: isn't it possible to write models without creating any app ?

Answer (score 0):

migration on django is an app basis.

> migrations are created and run on a per-app basis, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/

so you should create an app and add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` as levi suggest. However, it is possible if you're kind a want to only use one app to manage all the models for your db under models.py, BUT it's messy.

i recommend to use the migration on app basis.